# Probability for Rolling 10 tethedrons 100 times

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, standard-deviation, expectation

I am pretty confused about how to form the probability distribution function of the following question:

Suppose you have a tetrahedron with numbers 1,2,3,4 on respective faces. If you roll 10 such tetrahedrons 100 times, what will be the mean value of the number and the variance you get. Plot the distribution as a function of number. I think the number refers to the sum of the values on all the tetrahedrons. How can I form the PDF of this case I think I shall think of them as 10-tuples in analogy with the two dice throw example, but we have 100 throws here. Any help, suggestion and hint will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us what you have done.

Comment: Well actually I am pretty puzzled by this situation I think it will turn out to be some sort of multinomial distribution but I cannot write the probability mass function. I can also visualize it as an array of 10x100 dimension but it seems that this will not aid me much.